# Simple 2d array in c,Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, file

My code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int  i=0,totalNums,totalNum,j=0;
    size_t count;
    float numbers[20][100];
    char *line = malloc(100);

    FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen("vel.txt", "r");


    if (myFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error Reading File\n");
        exit (0);
    }

    while(getline(&line, &count, myFile)!=-1) {
        for (; count > 0; count--, j++)
            sscanf(line, "%f", &numbers[i][j]);
        i++;
    }

    totalNums = 100;
    totalNum = 20;
    for (i=0 ; i<totalNums ; i++) {
      for (j=0 ; j<totalNum ; j++) {
        printf("\n%f",  numbers[i][j]);
      }
    }
    fclose(myFile);
    return 0;
}
```

My goal is to read 2d array.
My vel.txt

```
2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0
2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0
2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0 2900.0
3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0
3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0
3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0
3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0 3600.0
4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0
4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0 4700.0
4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0
5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0
5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0
5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0
5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0
5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0
5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0
5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 4900.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5100.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0
5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0
5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0
5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0 5400.0
```

I have compiled with gcc my code but I got :

```
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~$ ./n1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Why?

Comment: Do you have the core file? Did you try to debug? The debugger is your friend, either do a post-mortem debugging with the core file or run the application inside the debugger. Then look at the backtrace to find out where the segfault happens.

Comment: 1) `sscanf(line, "%f", &numbers[i][j]);` It has not changed reading position. and many times `count > 0; count--` then occurs out of range of array. 2) change to `size_t count = 0;  char *line = NULL;` then `getline(&line, &count, myFile` and Don't change `count`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY What should I change to read my array?

Comment: I got segmentation fault again.

Comment: Unrelated: Don't forget to `free` the allocated memory.

Comment: @RichardRublev  example up post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fix like this

```
size_t count=0;
float numbers[20][100];
char *line = NULL;
```

...

```
while(i < 20 && getline(&line, &count, myFile)!=-1) {
    int len = 0, pos = 0;
    j = 0;
    while(j < 100 && 1 == sscanf(line + pos, "%f%n", &numbers[i][j++], &len))
        pos += len;
    i++;
}
free(line);
totalNums = i;
totalNum = 100;//j;
```

Comment: Works perfect now!

Answer (score 4):

Some bugs:

- `float numbers[20][100];` is a 20 x 100 array. This:

  ```
  totalNums = 100;
  totalNum = 20;
  for (i=0 ; i<totalNums ; i++) {
    for (j=0 ; j<totalNum ; j++) {
      printf("\n%f",  numbers[i][j]);
    }
  }
  ```

  iterates over a 100 x 20 array. The use of better variable names than "totalNums" (for example something like `max_x` and `max_y`) would likely have eliminated this bug.
- `count` is uninitialized before use. Enable compiler warnings.
- You don't `free()` the variable `line` anywhere. Actually there is no reason to use dynamic allocation here at all.

Comment: are you sure about the part about "not using dynamic allocation" ? Linux man page says that it must be a malloc-allocated buffer.

Comment: @4386427 Are you sure it doesn't simply say "allocated", in any memory?

Comment: It says: `If *lineptr is set to NULL and *n is set 0 before the call, then getline() will allocate a buffer...... Alternatively,  before  calling getline(), *lineptr can contain a pointer to a malloc(3)-allocated buffer *n bytes in size.` It also says `If the buffer is not large enough to hold the line, get‐
       line() resizes it with realloc(3), updating *lineptr and *n as necessary.`

Answer (score 2):

The following code:

```
while(getline(&line, &count, myFile)!=-1) {
    for (; count > 0; count--, j++)
        sscanf(line, "%f", &numbers[i][j]);
    i++;
}
```

Will put in `count` the** number of bytes read**. But in next line, you consider it as the **number of numbers to read**... And on number is at least composed of 2 bytes (one per character + one for the space).

You should try to read the line with some function like [`strtok`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok). Warning, this function is not so trivial to use, read carrefully the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Your `count` is not initialized before calling `getline`, try this:

```
size_t count = 100;
char *line = malloc(count);

while(getline(&line, &count, myFile)!=-1) { ... }
```

Comment: @flutter Again the same,will try with smaller array.

Comment: @RichardRublev - Read both answers and combine them. Count is not the number of floats per line so you can't use it in a for-loop.

Comment: An alternative is to do `count=0; line=NULL` and let `getline`handle the allocation